# How to find the position of Cursor to select text from that position in Edit text?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, richtextediting, inputconnection

I am working on Keyboard for android devices where i am Text editing options like Google Keyboard like (Text selection, copy paste etc).
for example i typed a text ABSCEONDER and now i want to selection some portion of text. like i want text selection from position E. What i did is i drooped cursor at position E manually. now how do i find the position of Cursor to select text from that position? can any one help?

```
 ExtractedText extractedText = mLatinIme.getCurrentInputConnection().getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0);
                if (extractedText == null || extractedText.text == null) return;
                int index = extractedText.text.length();
                mLatinIme.getCurrentInputConnection().setSelection(0, index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the cursor position from your `EditText` like this :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

              int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
              Layout layout = editText.getLayout();
              float x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(pos);

            }
        });
```

Comment: bro if it is in Input connection?  like if we are typing message on mobile then how do i  find the position?

Comment: if i use  int pos=mLatinIme.getCurrentInputConnection()  then getstartselection do not work.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @mohammadReza Abiri. I found the solution for this.

```
 ExtractedText extractedText = mLatinIme.getCurrentInputConnection().getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0);
        if (extractedText == null || extractedText.text == null) return;

        int selectionStart = extractedText.selectionStart;
        int selectionEnd = extractedText.selectionEnd;

        mLatinIme.getCurrentInputConnection().setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd + 1);
```